# Getting the TreeViewItem on newly created items

Tags: silverlight, treeview, treeviewitem, itemcontainergenerator

There has to be a better way then the following for getting "childItem"

```
    TaskItem task = (sender as Canvas).DataContext as TaskItem;
    TaskItem child = Tasks.CreateTask("New task", task);
    TreeViewItem item = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(task) as TreeViewItem;            

    item.UpdateLayout();
    TreeViewItem childItem = null;
    foreach (var i in item.GetDescendantContainers())
    {
        if (i.GetItem() == child)
            childItem = i;
    }
```

For some reason item.ItemGenerator.ContainerFromItem(child) does not work (must be due to the item having just been created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item container generation is asynchronous, so you cannot assume the container will exist as soon as the item was added.  You will need to attach a handler to the [ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.statuschanged.aspx) event so your code will be informed when container generation is complete.

Dr. WPF's blog entry ["ItemsControl: 'G' is for Generator"](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/) has a good description of the problem and provides an example of using StatusChanged:

```
private void AddScooby()
{
    _scooby = new Character("Scooby Doo");
    Characters.Add(_scooby);
    CharacterListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged
        += OnStatusChanged;
}

private void OnStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CharacterListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status
        == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        CharacterListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged
            -= OnStatusChanged;
        ListBoxItem lbi = CharacterListBox.ItemContainerGenerator
            .ContainerFromItem(_scooby) as ListBoxItem;
        if (lbi != null)
        {
            lbi.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```